# How to remove the following error in Jslint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I am the first experience with Jslint/jshint,

Just received the error like this

```
ES5 option is now set per default
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The "ES5 option is now set per default" error is thrown when JSHint (version 2.0.0 and above only) encounters the es5 option with a value of true. - https://jslinterrors.com/es5-option-is-now-set-per-default

Comment: Which one? JSLint or JSHint?

Comment: BTW jshint & jslint are two different tools, try to be clearer about which one you are using

Answer (score -1):

The "ES5 option is now set per default" error is thrown when JSHint (version 2.0.0 and above only) encounters the es5 option with a value of true. Here's an example in which we set the es5 option so we can use reserved words as property identifers (which was not allowed in ES3):

```
/*jshint es5: true */
var x = {
    default: 10
};
```

ERROR here...

This error is raised to highlight a *pointless piece of code. If you're using JSHint 2.0.0 or above, the es5 option will be set to true by default, due to the fact that environments supporting the ES5 spec are now far more widespread.

You can simply remove the option from any JSHint directives or .jshintrc files. Select JSHint version 1.1.0 or below in the following example to see the difference from when the es5 option was not on by default:

```
var x = {
    default: 10
};
```

No errors here...